# HPE Haven: How to Invoke Speech Recognition API Using Curl?

Tags: windows, curl, speech-recognition, hp-haven

How can I use `curl` to invoke HPE Haven's Speech Recognition API? I only get a json response containing something called a `jobID`. Where's the speech recognition result?

Answer (score 2):

HPE Haven's Speech Recognition API can be called by using two `curl` commands. The first `curl` posts the audio/video file and returns a json object containing a `jobID`. A second `curl` command can retrieve the speech recognition result by referencing the `jobID`. Extracting the `jobID` and passing it to the second command can be tricky. Below is a Windows batch file that performs the whole process ultimately displaying the recognized text. This procedure uses the `jq` program available at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ to manipulate the json responses.

```
set ApiKey="<your HPE Haven Speech Recognition key>"
set file="<some audio/video filename>"
curl -sS -X POST --form "file=@%file%" --form "apikey=%ApiKey%" -k https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/async/recognizespeech/v1 > curljobidout.txt
jq -r ".jobID" curljobidout.txt > JobID.txt
set /p JobID= < JobID.txt
curl -sS https://api.havenondemand.com/1/job/result/%JobID%?apikey=%ApiKey% > curlresultout.txt
jq -r ".actions[0].result.document[0].content" < curlresultout.txt
```